# Windows 8 "Run" not opening in the bottom left corner

Tags: windows, windows-8

On my Windows 8 Desktop the "Run" window doesn't open in the bottom left corner of the screen anymore. On all my other desktops, at work or at home, Windows 7 and 8, WIN+R opens the "Run" window in the bottom left corner.

How can I fix this?

To clarify: Currently the run box opens up on the center of the main screen (so yes, multi-monitor with two screens with different resolutions). But I've seen it come up in different locations from time to time, but it doesn't match the window state of the current foreground window, I already tried that.

Also the volume mixer opens up in the middle of the main screen, too. And not right above the little speaker icon in the tray bar.

The PC problems window opens up correctly above its icon, though.

What I already tried:

- Changing display resolution (window still in the center)
- Changing primary display to second screen (run opened in the center on both screens)

Comment: So where does it open, or is the location random? Also, do you have a multi-monitor setup?

Comment: Currently it opens up on the center of the main screen (so yes, multi-monitor with two screens with different resolutions).
But I've seen it come up in different locations, but it doesn't match the window state of the current foreground window, I already tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using ATI/AMD video drivers on this computer?  Was having the same issue and uninstalling the HydraVision component from the catalyst software suite seemed to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for this idea! I had HydraVision installed and tried to uninstall it but the AMD uninstaller said something about missing files for uninstall.
Then I updated to the latest Catalyst (13.5 as of this post) and HydraVision was not in the uninstall list anymore. 
But when I got into the CCC and disabled the Desktop-Manager under HydrasVision the run box appeared where it should. The other windows were fixed, too!

Answer (score 0):

Try going into `Folder Options` and then in the `View` tab click on `Reset Folders`. Any results?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

**-Windows 10.0.19045.3448
-3 monitors (NEC) on a FirePro v7900 card ATI/AMD 'FireGL V'
driver: 15.201.1151.1008**
not in the span monitor mode (eyefinity) where the monitor appears in windows as the sum of the width of all of the monitors
in the running programs (task manager details) I found
\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\HydraVision\HydraDM.exe
\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\HydraVision\HydraDM64.exe

I killed HydraDM.exe -no reboot and no change.  eg run box still appearing center of screen sometimes or lower left sometimes on main monitor 'randomly' changing

**I killed HydraDM64.exe -no reboot and the 'run box center of screen' problem hasn't appeared in several dozen instsances**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).